# Why does this inequality hold (for a probability problem in durrett)?

Tags: inequality

Let $S_{m,n} = X_{m+1} + \cdots + X_n.$

Suppose $|S_{m,k}| > 2a$, $|S_{m,j}| < 2a$ for $m\leq j< k$, and $|S_{k,n}| \leq a$.  Then these imply $|S_{m,n}| > a.$

This doesn't seem to follow via triangle inequality but it's supposedly true.  I need help.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

$$S_{m,n}=S_{m,k}+S_{k,n}\implies|S_{m,n}|\geqslant|S_{m,k}|-|S_{k,n}|$$